# Странное поведение Vector.push() и Array.push()

Tags: actionscript-3

Есть такой код:

```
public var Next:Vector.<Point>;
//..............
Next = new Vector.<Point>();
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var p:Point = new Point(i,i*2);//допустим
    Next.push(p);
//  Next[i] = p; //Эти варианты я тоже пробовал, с тем же результатом.
//  Next[Next.lenght] = p;
}
//Где-то дальше. Никаких манипуляций с вышеописанным вектором не было
for(var j:int = 0; j < Next.lenght; j++) {
   trace(Next[j].x, Next[j].y);//у всех элементов значения x = 9  y = 18 (последней итерации)
}
```

Даже если сразу после заполнения вектора вывести его, или обратится к любому его элементу, вывод один и тот-же - последняя итерация.

P.S. Запускал отладчик, и там видно, как после каждого обращения push предыдущие значения обновляются. И что мне делать?

Comment: Проверь вектор сразу после создания, если там правильный, значит, где-то ещё портишь.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что вместо нового объекта какждый раз здесь мусолится один и тот же. `p` перезаписывается вместо того чтобы пересоздаваться. В то же время вектор `Next` хранит только ссылки на него а не сами значения. Не совсем ясно где находится этот код, по хорошему нужно увидеть всю функцию/метод целиком. Попробуй такие варианты возможно они решат проблему:

1. Объяви `p` до цикла, но на одном уровне с ним.
2. Объяви `p` в одной строке, но присвой значени уже в следующей. Вообще присвоение значений и тем более какие-то расчеты при объявлении переменной это плохо.
3. Можешь выкинуть `p`, так как в этом коде оно промежуточное звено. `Next.push(new Point(i, i*2))`. Ну или если очень надо им порулить то: `var p:Point = Next.push(new Point(i, i*2))`

P.S. Не рекомендую именовать переменные с заглавной буквы. В AS Так принято именовать классы. Если вы так хотите визуально отделить публичные переменные от приватных, то вместо этого привытным можете добавить знак подчерка перед именем `_someVar`.

Comment: Вообще-то, вызов `new Point(...)` создает новый объект, так что код должен нормально отрабатывать.

Comment: @Vesper `new Point(...)` и создает. Но в результате в векторе остаётся только последний созданный экземпляр. Очевидно, что каждый элемент вектора ссылается на один объект. Почему это произошло мне тоже не совсем ясно, не хватает контекста в котором этот код выполняется. Тем не менее я уверен что третий совет сработает точно.

Comment: Ну да, в голом виде код что с Р, что без Р должен отработать правильно, создав вектор из разных объектов. Значит, "не было манипуляций с вектором" - неверно.